# React-native: conditional rendering with loginState

Tags: reactjs, react-native, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a login for a **React Native** app.

But the conditional rendering is not working, really don't know what I am doing wrong. (I am new to **react native**)

The **isLoggedIn** state checks if the user has a valid `refreshToken`. The token class works only thing that isn't working is the rendering after logging in.

InsightsApiDriver

```js
  isValidRefreshToken() {
    return (
      this.refreshToken !== undefined &&
      new Date().getTime() - this.refreshToken.datetime.getTime() <
        1 * 60 * 1000
    );
  }
```

MainContainer

```js
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(undefined);
  useEffect(() => {
    SecureStore.getItemAsync("refreshToken")
      .then((tokenJson) => (tokenJson ? JSON.parse(tokenJson) : undefined))
      .then((tokenObj) => {
        if (tokenObj !== undefined) {
          tokenObj.datetime = new Date(tokenObj.datetime);
        }
        global.AppInsightDriver = new InsightsApiDriver(tokenObj);
        setIsLoading(false);
        setIsLoggedIn(global.AppInsightDriver.isValidRefreshToken());
      });
  }, []);
```

```js
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {console.log(isLoggedIn)}
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <Tab.Navigator
          initialRouteName={routes.session}
          screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
              let iconName;
              switch (route.name) {
                case routes.session:
                  iconName = focused ? "speedometer" : "speedometer-outline";
                  break;
                case routes.settings:
                  iconName = focused ? "settings" : "settings-outline";
                  break;
                case routes.about:
                  iconName = focused ? "help-circle" : "help-circle-outline";
                  break;
                case routes.login:
                  iconName = focused ? "log-in" : "log-in-outline";
                default:
                  iconName = focused ? "log-in" : "log-in-outline";
                  break;
              }
              return <Icon name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
            },
            tabBarActiveTintColor: "#FFC62C",
            tabBarInactiveTintColor: "white",
            headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#1F2341" },
            headerTitleAlign: "center",
            headerTintColor: "#FFC62C",
            headerTitle: () => (
              <HeaderTitle
                SmartgridoneLogo={SmartgridoneLogo}
                routeName={route.name}
              />
            ),
            tabBarStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "#1F2341",
            },
          })}
        >
          <Tab.Screen name={routes.session} component={SessionScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name={routes.settings} component={SettingScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name={routes.about} component={AboutScreen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      ) : (
        <Tab.Navigator
          initialRouteName={routes.login}
          screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
              let iconName;
              switch (route.name) {
                case routes.session:
                  iconName = focused ? "speedometer" : "speedometer-outline";
                  break;
                case routes.settings:
                  iconName = focused ? "settings" : "settings-outline";
                  break;
                case routes.about:
                  iconName = focused ? "help-circle" : "help-circle-outline";
                  break;
                case routes.login:
                  iconName = focused ? "log-in" : "log-in-outline";
                default:
                  iconName = focused ? "log-in" : "log-in-outline";
                  break;
              }
              return <Icon name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
            },
            tabBarActiveTintColor: "#FFC62C",
            tabBarInactiveTintColor: "white",
            headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#1F2341" },
            headerTitleAlign: "center",
            headerTintColor: "#FFC62C",
            headerTitle: () => (
              <HeaderTitle
                SmartgridoneLogo={SmartgridoneLogo}
                routeName={route.name}
              />
            ),
            tabBarStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "#1F2341",
            },
          })}
        >
          <Tab.Screen name={routes.login} component={LoginScreen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      )}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

Comment: Could you show the code where you declare ‘isLoggedIn’?

Comment: does the console.log for isLoggedIn show correct value?

Comment: @tahaf10 Yes it shows false when starting the app.

Comment: And after you login, does it still show false?

Comment: That I dont know, But if I refresh expo. the logged in screens are shown @tahaf10

Comment: Where's the conditional rendering for isLoading state? and also do check if the refreshToken is getting stored in the Storage after login

Comment: After refreshing expo is showing `TRUE`

Comment: Add your LoginScreen component code as well in the original post

Answer (score 1):

The useEffect hook which you're using is more or less acting like a componentDidMount method. Which means it only runs when the screen is first mounted. Initially when you run the app, the isLoggedIn state gets set as false. But after you're logged in, this state is not being updated or atleast you haven't mentioned this in the code. If you also mention the routes.login method then it'll be easier to debug. Second time when you refresh app, the mount method sets the isLoggedIn state as true because the token is valid. So there's your issue

Comment: @Bataklik edit in your original post

Answer (score 0):

You need to render the whole navigation container when user re-authenticated by adding `isLoggedIn` on `useEffect` dependencies array

```js
useEffect(() => {
    SecureStore.getItemAsync("refreshToken")
      .then((tokenJson) => (tokenJson ? JSON.parse(tokenJson) : undefined))
      .then((tokenObj) => {
        if (tokenObj !== undefined) {
          tokenObj.datetime = new Date(tokenObj.datetime);
        }
        global.AppInsightDriver = new InsightsApiDriver(tokenObj);
        setIsLoading(false);
        setIsLoggedIn(global.AppInsightDriver.isValidRefreshToken());
      });
  }, [isLoggedIn]);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause an infinite loop since in the effect `isLoggedIn` is being changed

Comment: Yes. Not a very good approach

Comment: This should trigger rerender only when user login or logout

Answer (score 0):

SecureStore doesnt provides an event listener for value changes so whenever `refreshToken` changes you need to recalculate the value of `isLoggedIn`. That would mean prop drilling `setIsLoggedIn` down to every component where the token is  changed, or opting to use some form of state management. (`React.useContext` is nice)

With that in mind you will be using the following code at least twice, so you might as well put it in its own file (let's call it updateLogin.js), and export it as a function

updateLogin.js

```js
// pass setIsLoggedIn as a parameter
export default updateIsLoggedIn=setIsLoggedIn=>{
  SecureStore.getItemAsync("refreshToken")
      .then((tokenJson) => (tokenJson ? JSON.parse(tokenJson) : undefined))
      .then((tokenObj) => {
        if (tokenObj !== undefined) {
          tokenObj.datetime = new Date(tokenObj.datetime);
        }
        global.AppInsightDriver = new InsightsApiDriver(tokenObj);
        setIsLoading(false);
        setIsLoggedIn(global.AppInsightDriver.isValidRefreshToken());
      });
}
```

Now MainContainer becomes:

```js
import updateLogin from '../helpers/updateLogin';
/*
.
.
.
*/
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(undefined);
useEffect(() => {
  updateLogin(setIsLoggedIn);
}, []);
```

Then in your LoginScreen in whatever function where you write refreshToken to SecureStore after the write is finished just called `updateIsLoggedIn(setIsLoggedIn)`.

Dont forget to either prop drill `setIsLoggedIn`.